# How to execute a PHP spider/scraper but without it timing out

Tags: php, web-crawler

Basically I need to get around max execution time.

I need to scrape pages for info at varying intervals, which means calling the bot at those intervals, to load a link form the database and scrap the page the link points to.

The problem is, loading the bot.  If I load it with javascript (like an Ajax call) the browser will throw up an error saying that the page is taking too long to respond yadda yadda yadda, plus I will have to keep the page open.

If I do it from within PHP I could probably extend the execution time to however long is needed but then if it does throw an error I don't have the access to kill the process, and nothing is displayed in the browser until the PHP execute is completed right?

I was wondering if anyone had any tricks to get around this?  The scraper executing by itself at various intervals without me needing to watch it the whole time.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "nothing is displayed in the browser until the PHP execute is completed"

You can use [`flush()`](http://uk.php.net/flush) to work around this:

> `flush()`
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>
> Flushes the output buffers of PHP and whatever backend PHP is using (CGI, a web server, etc). This effectively tries to push all the output so far to the user's browser.

Comment: Thanks dude I'll use this in combination with set_time_limit() Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`set_time_limit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) as such:

```
set_time_limit(0);
// Do Time Consuming Operations Here
```

Comment: Thanks dude I'll use this in combination with flush() Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at how [Sphider (PHP Search Engine)](http://www.sphider.eu/) does this.

Basically you will just process some part of the sites you need, do your thing, and go on to the next request if there's a continue=true parameter set.

Answer (score 0):

run via CRON and split spider into chunks, so it will only do few chunks at once. call from CRON with different parameteres to process only few chunks.